# emplace unordered_set in unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, move, unordered-map, emplace

How can I add a (statically defined) unordered_set to an unordered_map, without having to copy the unordered_set?

I tried this:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<std::string>> my_map;
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  my_map.emplace(i, {"foo", "bar"});
```

and this:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<std::string>> my_map;
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  my_map.insert(i, std::move(std::unordered_set<std::string>({"foo", "bar"})));
```

but none of them compiles, I get these errors (respectively):

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<std::basic_string<char> > >::emplace(int&, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
```

and

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<std::basic_string<char> > >::insert(int&, std::remove_reference<std::unordered_set<std::basic_string<char> > >::type)’
```

Comment: This looks more like you want an `unordered_map` of `unordered_set`s (which is not what you say in the question). Please clarify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Braced initializers are one of the edge cases that perfect forwarding is not so perfect about.

The issue is that braced initializers passed to function template parameters are in a non-deduced context and compilers are not allowed to deduce a type for them.

Luckily, the fix is pretty easy: just be explicit about the use of `std::initializer_list`.

```
my_map.emplace(i, std::initializer_list<std::string>{"foo", "bar"});
```

The usual way to solve this issue is by doing something like:

```
auto list = { "foo", "bar" };
my_map.emplace(i, list);
```

But this doesn't work for `std::string`s because `decltype(list)` is deduced as `std::initializer_list<const char*>`.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of maps (both `map` and `unordered_map`) are of type `using value type = std::pair<key_t, mapped_type>`. Therefore, `emplace` does not pass its arguments to the `unordered_set<string>` constructor!

Once you realize that, the solution is [easy](https://ideone.com/8VysTj):

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<std::string>> my_map;
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    my_map.emplace(i, std::unordered_set<std::string>{"foo", "bar"});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following code:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  my_map.emplace(i, std::unordered_set<std::string>({"foo","bar"}));
```

It will move the unordered set into the unordered map.

Answer (score 1):

In order to insert something in a `std::map<Key, Value>`, you need to insert a `std::pair<Key, Value>`

Change:

```
my_map.insert(i, std::move(std::unordered_set<std::string>({"foo", "bar"})));
```

into:

```
my_map.insert( std::make_pair(i, std::unordered_set<std::string>({"foo", "bar"})));
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: The temporary is already a rvalue, so the `std::move` that you copied from OP is pointless.

Comment: I guess you meant `std::make_pair` instead of `std::pair`?

Comment: Yes I did indeed. Thanks!